# Strange load error when

Tags: magento-1.9, xml

We currently have a strange error on our website. Some productpages are not loaded, the php error that is displayed is:

How can we solve this?

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 136: parser error : Double hyphen within comment: <!-- My Applications
    <customer_account>
        <r  in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/home/d...', 450, Array)
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(450): simplexml_load_string('getFileLayoutUpdatesXml('frontend', 'theme', 'headtheme', '1')
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(347): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchFileLayoutUpdates()
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(224): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->merge('default')
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->load()
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(109): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayoutUpdates()
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show your `XML` file content where you changed things for `<customer_account>` ? there looks to be a typo or invalid xml issue